# How to connect to VPN from the command line in Linux?

Tags: linux, openvpn, networkmanager

I have different tunnels that I configured using the network manager GUI.

When I login to my desktop, I'm connected to the internet without any tunnels. To connect to a tunnel, I usually click on the network manager tray icon > VPN connections > Some VPN

I need that done automatically on startup, so I need to know how to do that in the cli.

It would also be nice if I could make sure that no application connects to the internet before the connection is tunneled.

Any ideas?

I'm using Ubuntu 12 and openvpn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have nmcli in that version

```
nmcli con list
```

That will list connections you have setup. Find the VPN one

```
nmcli con up uuid <uuid>
```

Comment: I tried this in the cli but it requires a secret: "no valid VPN secrets"

Comment: I was executing this as root, therefore the secret was not available. I had to execute this as the user that was logged in. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but when I try it as my normal user, I get `Connection activation failed: Not authorized to control networking.` Any ideas?

Comment: For me, the first command was `nmcli con show` (`list` didn't exist).

Answer (score 2):

This is what the OpenVPN HOWTO says:
"If you install OpenVPN via an RPM package on Linux, the installer will set up an initscript. When executed, the initscript will scan for .conf configuration files in /etc/openvpn, and if found, will start up a separate OpenVPN daemon for each file.". Ubuntu is derived from Debian, and may have a different structure.

Check in /etc/openvpn if you have that dir and .conf files, then if you have in /etc/rc5.d/ a link to the initscript. To check if the tunnel is up, you may ping the other side of the vpn.

Answer (score 0):

For authorization, you can use:

```
nmcli con up id <your vpn name> -ask
```

you'll be asked for missing password or username